# using curl to save output of php file to new file on server

Tags: php, session, curl

My plan is to create php 'template' files which will create various reports for the users of the site on demand.  What I want to do is get the output of the php file and save it as a new file on the server.  The curl and file creation works, but ...

**Problems and questions :**

- When using curl I no longer have access to any of the $_SESSION variables which are set for the user logged in.  I need to be able to access these in my output.php file to actually create the correct content I want in the file.  Is there a way to pass/allow access to the $_SESSION variables?  If not, is there a way I can post data along with curl... such as posting the user ID or something along those lines?
- Is the mode required when using recursive = true for mkdir?
- Lastly... my original plan was to store these 'template' files outside of the public_html directory so there was no direct access to the files... only through my scripts although it appears curl can only save the output of the php file when given a url.  With that said, it appears the files must be accessible via the web.  Is there a way to give curl a filepath such as '/home/test/template/output.php instead and still process the file and save the actual output of it?

I am up for any suggestions that work EXCEPT file_get_contents as I have fopen disabled.  Would using output_buffer instead be better in this situation?

**example call to create a report :**

```
get_archive('http://www.test.com/template/output.php', '/home/test/public_html/reports/', 'newreport.html');

function get_archive($file, $local_path, $newfilename) 
{ 
    // if location does not exist create it
    if(!file_exists($local_path)) 
    {
        mkdir($local_path, 0755, true);
    }

    $out = fopen($local_path.$newfilename,"wb");
    if ($out == false){ 
      exit; 
    }

    $ch = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

}
```

**simple example template file (output.php) :** This would obviously be much more extensive, but you should get the idea.

```
<?php

// These files can be included only if INCLUDE_CHECK is defined
require '/home/test/public_html/custom/functions/connect.php';
require '/home/test/public_html/custom/functions/functions.php';
require '/home/test/public_html/custom/functions/session.php';

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">                                                         
                <?php

                    //create report contents
                                    echo $_SESSION['user']['account_id']; // returns nothing    

                ?>

        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a wonky approach, but the basic issue is you need to set up cookies for curl requests to pass in session id.

Comment: What other way would you recommend?  This was the first that came to mind... I am open to anything.

Comment: I would render them on the fly each time, or if latency is expensive just store the curl data in the file and render the report on the fly.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I really wanted to use a template system for easy changes on my end rather than echo'ing everything into the file. I am saving the file because the purpose is to create the report on click and then allow the file to be downloaded by the user. What do you think?